# Android: Share to Gmail and Outlook App using Intent

Tags: android, html, email, android-intent, outlook

1. I am trying to share a HTML content to Gmail App and Outlook app. But, even after trying multiple times, Gmail App doesn't show inline images when I send Intent like

`intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(richText));`

Is there special attributes required in HTML  tag ?

2. For outlook app,

I have to send Intent like below to ensure body doesn't remain blank,

```
 ArrayList<String> extra_text = new ArrayList<String>();
 String body = String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(richText);    
 extra_text.add(body);
 intent.putStringArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, extra_text);
```

Still, I have no way to share HTML formatted tags to Outlook app using Intent. Kindly help.

Thanks,

Comment: "Gmail App doesn't show inline images when I send Intent" -- there is no requirement for any app to necessarily support arbitrary HTML via `ACTION_SEND`. In the case of Gmail, most likely they are using an `EditText` for the email composer, and `Html.fromHtml()` requires special support for processing `<img>` tags. Gmail may not have implemented that, perhaps for privacy/security reasons.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, is there a way I can support inline images in Gmail app by modifying some of the HTML attributes? For outlook app, is there a way to share rich text?

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. Waiting for Google and Microsoft folks to reply then :)